# Take the percentage after multiple grouping in R (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, percentage

I have the following table in R :

| id | var1 | var2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | A | X | 1 |
| ID2 | B | X | 2 |
| ID3 | C | X | 3 |
| ID4 | D | X | 4 |
| ID5 | A | Y | 2 |
| ID6 | C | Y | 5 |
| ID7 | B | Y | 3 |

And to group_by in dplyr the var1 and var2 and take the proportion of each grouping resulting to :

| id | var1 | var2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | A | X | 1/3 |
| ID2 | A | Y | 2/3 |
| ID3 | C | X | 3/8 |
| ID4 | C | Y | 5/8 |
| ID5 | B | X | 2/5 |
| ID6 | B | Y | 3/5 |
| ID7 | D | X | 1 |

I tried :

```
id = c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5","ID6","ID7")
var1 = c("A","B","C","D","A","C","B")
var2 = c(rep("X",4),rep("Y",3))
value = c(1,2,3,4,2,5,3)
data = data.frame(id,var1,var2,value);data
library(dplyr)
data%>%
  group_by(var1,var2)%>%
  summarise(prop = sum(value))
```

But it only group the var1 and var2.
Any help ?

Comment: From the output it looks like you only want to group by `var1`. Try `data %>% group_by(var1) %>% mutate(value = prop.table(value))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may works

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(var1)%>%
  mutate(value = value/sum(value)) %>%
  arrange(var1, var2)

  id    var1  var2  value
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 ID1   A     X     0.333
2 ID5   A     Y     0.667
3 ID2   B     X     0.4  
4 ID7   B     Y     0.6  
5 ID3   C     X     0.375
6 ID6   C     Y     0.625
7 ID4   D     X     1
```

Answer (score 0):

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, res := proportions(value), by = var1][order(var1)]
```

**base**

df$res <- ave(df$value, list(df$var1), FUN = proportions)